# Is there a way to make a function node override another function node?

Tags: function, node-red

I have a function node comparing to values in my node-red and outputting the greater one. I want it to:

1. Compare the 2 values and output the greater one.
2. Recompare the 2 values again after 5 seconds.
3. If the first value is greater, carry on outputting it else enter another function node.
4. It should ignore the first function node and carry on with the second function node.

Note: The 2 values are being constantly fed by a serial input. My problem is that it keeps passing into the first function then to the second. I want it to skip the first function node when the requirements are met and go to the second function node directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable in the flow or global context in the first function node and then you can check that value in a switch node to determine what branch to follow.

```
-------------      -----------      --------------     --------------
|   serial  |----->| switch  |----->| function 1 |---->| function 2 |
-------------      |         |---|  --------------  |  --------------
                   -----------   |                  | 
                                 |------------------|
```

Comment: Can I switch nodes based on time and not on msg.payload value?

Comment: you could include a delay node to change the timings of when the context variable is changed

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do it. I have a big problem though.

I made it such that if my serial input actually contains a value "x", then it switch. My problem is that after it switches, the value "x" from my input is gone and it goes back to the first branch.

I need it such that, as soon as it detects the value "x" in my input, change the branch permanently and not return to the first no matter what.

I hope it was clear. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: This is not the place for this type of discussion, post to the mailing list (Google Group) or the Slack team. Both are linked to from the Node-RED home page

Comment: I've marked it as accepted.

An example of the answer can be found here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/node-red/TbzLPoeB-XY/UE4be052BAAJ